# Проблема при установке maven на mac

Tags: maven, mac, terminal

Возникла проблема при установке maven на mac. После распаковки архива в директорию пользователя, пишу в терминале:

```
export M2_HOME=path_to_maven

export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Проверяю: `mvn -version` получаю `-bash: mvn: command not found`

Comment: `export` - штука одноразовая. Рекомендую не париться и поставить maven через homebrew.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не слышал, сейчас попробую, спасибо.